# KMM with CocoaPods. Error: cocoapods-generate requires CocoaPods >= 1.5.0

Tags: macos, cocoapods, kmm

I'm trying to add a simple CocoaPods dependency to a test kmm project as explained in [this tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-cocoapods.html#add-a-dependency-on-a-pod-library-from-the-cocoapods-repository)

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error

```
Executing of 'pod gen --platforms=ios --gen-directory=/Users/par/code/my/MyApplication/shared/build/cocoapods/synthetic/IOS --sources=https://cdn.cocoapods.org /Users/par/code/my/MyApplication/shared/shared.podspec' failed with code 1 and message: 
[!] cocoapods-generate requires CocoaPods >= 1.5.0
```

How to fix this error?

My setup

```
cocoapods version: 1.11.2
cocoapods-generate version: 1.4.1

Mac OS Big Sur 11.6
```

It looks like the version of [cocoapods-generate](https://github.com/square/cocoapods-generate) is obsolete. The latest version of the script is 2.2.2

No matter how hard I've tried, I was not able to upgrade cocoapods-generate past 1.4.1
I'm installing it with this command

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-generate
```

I have found this piece of info in [this issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/4338#issuecomment-771493235)

> The underlying error is that cocoapods-generate at version 2.2.1 cannot be installed on ruby 3, because it depends on cocoapods-disable-podfile-validations ~> 0.1.1,and the only version of cocoapods-disable-podfile-validations satisfying that (0.1.1) needs ruby ~> 2.1.

Have no idea how to solve this puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by downgrading ruby to 2.6

```
brew install rvm
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash  
rvm install ruby-2.6.0
```

Answer (score -2):

had to run this:

```
gem install cocoapods-generate
```